# Convert every 3 rows from a file into a key value array

Tags: python

I have a text file with multiple lines. How can I assign each row to the key in multiples of 3?

Text file:

> ```
> 123
> 123
> 01/01/2023
> 1234
> 1234
> 01/01/2023
> 12345
> 12345
> 01/01/2023
> ```

Python:

```
def build_list():
    key = ['workorder', 'invoicenum', 'compdate']
    with open('invoice.txt', 'r') as file:
        info = file.read().rstrip('\n')

    return info
```

Output should look like this:

```
['workorder: 123', 'invoicenum': 123, 'compdate': '01/01/2023'],
['workorder: 1234', 'invoicenum': 1234, 'compdate': '01/01/2023'],
['workorder: 12345', 'invoicenum': 12345, 'compdate': '01/01/2023']
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the values in your output array are strings or dictionaries, but here's one way to achieve what you're looking for:

```py
def build_list():
    with open('invoice.txt', 'r') as file:
        info = [l.strip() for l in file.readlines()]
    for idx, line in enumerate(info):
        if idx % 3 == 0:
            yield [f'workorder: {info[idx]}', f'invoicenum: {info[idx + 1]}', f'compdate: {info[idx + 2]}']


list(build_list())
```

Answer (score 0):

With short *iterator* approach:

```
def build_list():
    keys = ['workorder', 'invoicenum', 'compdate']
    info = []
    with open('invoice.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            info.append(dict(zip(keys, map(str.strip, [line, next(f), next(f)]))))
    return info

print(build_list())
```

---

```
[{'workorder': '123', 'invoicenum': '123', 'compdate': '01/01/2023'}, {'workorder': '1234', 'invoicenum': '1234', 'compdate': '01/01/2023'}, {'workorder': '12345', 'invoicenum': '12345', 'compdate': '01/01/2023'}]
```